# Prove that the Weierstrass $\wp$- function satisfies $\wp''\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)=2(e_1-e_2)(e_1-e_3)$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-functions

I am reading Apostol's *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory*. And I am stuck on exercise 8 of Chapter 1. The problem asks to show that $$\wp''\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)=2(e_1-e_2)(e_1-e_3),$$ where $e_1=\wp\left(\frac{\omega_1}{2}\right)$, $e_2=\wp\left(\frac{\omega_2}{2}\right)$, and $e_3=\wp\left(\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}\right)$.

I did not know how to approach the problem, so I started by differentiating the differential equation for $\wp$ and get $\wp''(z)=6\wp^2(z)-\frac{1}{2}g_2$. Therefore, $\wp''(e_1)=6e_1-\frac{1}{2}g_2$. Then using the original differential equation, and plugging in $e_1, e_2, e_3$, we have $$g_2e_1+g_3=4e_1^3,$$ $$g_2e_2+g_3=4e_2^3,$$ $$g_2e_3+g_3=4e_3^3.$$ We can solve for $g_2$ and plug it back to get $\wp''(e_1)=6e_1^2-2(e_2^2+e_2e_3+e_3^2)$. I cannot proceed from there.

Comment: Continuing down the line, I solved the problem by interchanging $e_1$, $e_2$, $e_3$ using the same formulas.

Comment: if $f(z)$ is elliptic (doubly periodic) and holomorphic (no pole on $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$) then it is entire and bounded so it is constant by Liouville's theorem. So all you have to do is checking the poles of the LHS and the RHS are the same (and I prefer [Diamond's book](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Fred%20Diamond%20Jerry%20Shurman%20A%20First%20Course%20in%20Modular%20Forms.pdf) )

Comment: Thank you so much. And thanks for the book recommendation.